# Replace Quote with Unicode Symbol in Text

Tags: c#, xml, unicode

In my XML I need to replace the `&quot;` symbol with the unicode symbol of `\u0022`.

I've tried `xml = xml.Replace("&quot;", "\u0022");` but when I view the xml in the debugger I just see ".

I need `Customer="&quot;Customer&quot;"` to become `Customer="\u0022Customer\u0022"`

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: [2.4.4.5 String Literals(C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `xml = xml.Replace(@"&quot;", @"\u0022");`